# How to mount /dev/disk1 with write permissions from Recovery Mode?

Tags: macos, permission, filesystem, mount, hfs+

Using `Command + R` at boot, I entered recovery mode but the /private/etc/ directory is Read-Only. Is it possible to unmount the disk then mount it again with write permissions?

```
# sw_vers
ProductName:    Mac OS X
ProductVersion:    10.8.5
BuildVersion:    12F45
```

Comment: In recovery mode, you're booted from a virtual disk (contained in a compressed read-only disk image on a hidden partition) *not* your regular startup volume. Your regular startup volume should be mounted at something like /Volumes/Macintosh HD (or whatever your regular startup volume is named), so try accessing `"/Volumes/Macintosh HD/private/etc"`.

Comment: Thanks! I changed into the `"/Volumes/Mac OS X Base System/etc"`. That's read-only as well. How can I mount it with write permissions?

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list` and `mount` (both entered in Terminal) to your question [by editing it](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/324511/edit)! Don't post it as comment!

Comment: @klanomath it would be difficult to get the outputs from the macbook in recovery mode to my desktop, sorry!

Comment: Usually you can't mount disk devices because they don't contain a file system (e.g. disk0: internal ssd or hdd, disk0 and disk1 (ssd & hdd = Fusion Drive) disk1: (or disk2 respectively) disk image containing a partition with the Mac OS X Base System. The temp RAM disks (disk2/3-~disk12/disk13) are an exception.

Comment: @user287980 You should be able to open Safari in the Utilities window (in Recovery Mode > "Get Help Online") and visit apple.stackexchange.com! Login with your credentials (if you are registered) and add the output. Or take a pic and upload it!

Comment: Reading and summing up all your questions: you are booting from an old recovery system but your internal drive is formatted to APFS. Your old recovery system (10.8.5) doesn't contain an APFS driver which was introduced years later in the late 10.12 system. You won't be able to mount disk0s2!

Comment: @klanomath What about booting the internet recovery, that should download more (the most) recent recovery, I guess. Wouldn't it help?

Answer (score 3):

When started in the Recovery Partition, choose Disk Utility from the list and click **Continue**. I'm assuming you are using 10.8.5 Mountain Lion.

[image]

Select **Macintosh HD** in the list of volumes on the left side and click **Mount** button on the toolbar. The volume will be mounted read-write and you can close **Disk Utility**, open **Terminal** and type:

```
cd /Volumes/Macintosh\ HD/etc
```

and work on files in that folder as you please.

Note that **/private/etc** and **/etc** are the same folders.

Comment: Hey boris, I'm looking at the Disk Utility window now but "disk1" and the Startup Disk beneath it don't allow me to **mount**. Most of the buttons (Unmount, Eject, etc) at the top of Disk Utility are unavailable.

Comment: @user287980 Select the volume or disk on the left and use First Aid to check for errors in the file system or partition table. Is this a known good volume/disk?

Comment: First Aid reported "The volume Mac OS X Base System appears to be OK." and I don't have reason to believe there's anything wrong with the volume/disk. Strange. Any ideas?

Comment: @user287980 Volume "Mac OS X Base System" is not your internal system volume as you can tell by the white icon instead of hard disk icon. White icon is for a mounted read-only image on the Recovery Partition. Your disk must have silver hard disk icon.

Comment: The partition was already mounted. I have unmounted it and mounted it back as you suggest, but it's still read-only.

Answer (score 0):

In macOS with signed system volumes, you can no longer edit these files trivially.

On 10.8.5 and a few releases past that, if you select terminal application in the utilities menu when booted to recovery mode, the OS prepares your volume for read and write access.

The benefit of this solution is it works across several versions of macOS where the mount command changes as does HFS and APFS change the underlying mount points.

Comment: I don't think this is true anymore, opening the Terminal on the Sierra booter, and the drive is mounted as read only.

Comment: Also doesn't work for me (MacOS 10.15.7).

Comment: You’re correct @DavidFerenczyRogožan. On macOS 10.8.5 this was trivially easy. I have edited the post to explain this. If you need this I recommend you ask a new question listing your macOS version and build and link here explaining that the old method no longer works.